# How to make multiple data frames from a list in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following data frames:
(1) table of gene ontology (GO) results:

```
GO <- c("biotic","defense","hormone")
geneID <- c("ENSG01/ENSG02/ENSG03","ENSG02/ENSG03","ENSG01/ENSG03/ENSG04/ENSG05")
resGO <- data.frame(GO, geneID)
```

(2) normalized read count matrix:

```
norm <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow = 5)
rownames(norm) <- c("ENSG01","ENSG02","ENSG03","ENSG04","ENSG05")
colnames(norm) <- c("B","IF1","IF2","PF1","PF2")
norm <- data.frame(norm)
```

I want to extract the list of genes from my GO table and then create multiple data frames of my normalized read count matrix, each subsetted based on the extracted lists of genes. I've tried the following for loops but my output of data frames are not subsetted. Based on my GO results table, df1 should have 3 rows (ie. 3 genes), df2 2 rows (ie. 2 genes) and df3 4 rows (ie. 4 genes). Could someone please help me out? Thank you!

```
genelist <- list()
df <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(resGO)){
    genes <- resGO[i,2]
    genes <- strsplit(genes , split = "/")
    genelist[[i]] <- genes
    for(p in 1:length(genelist)){
        genes_norm <- norm %>%
            filter(rownames(norm) %in% unlist(genelist))
        df[[p]] <- genes_norm
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the R loop, the code below now works:

```
genelist <- list()
df <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(resGO)){
    genes <- resGO[i,2]
    genes <- strsplit(genes , split = "/")
    genelist[[i]] <- genes
    
    for(p in 1:length(genelist)){
    genes_norm <- norm %>%
        filter(rownames(norm) %in% unlist(genelist[p]))
    df[[p]] <- genes_norm
    }
}
```